# Wireless problems, doesnt seem to have any easy fix

Tags: wireless

I was on my laptop dell latitude d630(wireless was working just fine) then out of no where it stopped working but if use a wireless usb adapter i can reconnect i have tried sudo get-apt install firmware-b43-installer and i tried purging the bwml(something), i have rebooted removed the adapter and im still not able to connect to the wireless, i can see all the available networks but it wont let me connect to any, i have passwords for all of them, but when it times out it prompts me to enter the wireless password again and then repeats the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have A Dell Latitude D630, running Ubuntu 11.10, and connect to my local Access Point (WPA2-PSK) with ease, and have connected to an Open (no security) AP.

Click on the Wireless icon in the top row of the screen, make sure that **Enable Networking** and "**Enable Wireless**" are checked; then  select "**Edit Connections**". Click the "**Wireless**" tab. For each connection listed, select it, click "**Edit**". In the window that opens, click the "**Wireless Security**" tab and ensure that the "**Security**" is set to the "right" value for that connection, and that the "Password" is correct (You can click on the "Show password" box to see the password).

I use the shipped-with-the-kernel `b43.ko` driver module `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko`, not "sudo get-apt install firmware-b43-installer and i tried purging the bwml(something)".

Run this command `sudo modprobe 43`, wait 7 seconds, then `tail -n 30 /var/log/kern.log`.

Use this method:

1. Cause the event (failure to connect in this case) to take place.
2. Do `ls -rlt /var/log` to get a reverse time-ordered list of log files.
3. For each of the "recent" log files, inspect the last several lines, and try to figure out what really happened.

Your problem report lacked details and clarity. I've tried to guess what you mean/want, but please make it easier for me next time.